# Trouble with DATE_FORMAT and STR_TO_TIME with AM/PM

Tags: mysql

I need to get the 24 hour time of a string, but I can only get the 12 hour for some reason using Mysql.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('3/13/2018 9:28:07 PM',  '%m/%d/%Y %T');
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('3/13/2018 9:28:07 PM',  '%m/%d/%Y %T') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-03-13 09:28:07                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried a variety of methods and thought it was working correctly, which it does, before noon....

I am trying to use it to limit the returned results to only things that have changed since the last time I ran the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%T is for time in 24 hour notation, so STR_TO_DATE is ignoring the PM/AM part of your time. You need to use %r. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for details.

Comment: Nick, you are awesome! For some reason I was thinking I wanted to use the %T to GET the format I wanted like with DATE_FORMAT, not to properly parse what I was supplying.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to datetime with time zone then use date format %T.

select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('3/13/2018 9:28:07 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %r'), '%T')

21:28:07